# Paperclip before upload callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip

I am working on a rails application that uses Timecop gem for "time traveling" and I have a problem... When I try to upload a file on Amazon S3 using Paperclip, S3 returns me

```
<Error><Code>RequestTimeTooSkewed</Code><Message>The difference between the request time and the current time is too large.</Message>
```

I think a "before_upload" callback on paperclip will help me to reset time to the real time, perform upload and travel back in the past... There is such a callback? What I found till now was just after_ callbacks :(

Answer (score 0):

try doing it in the `before_post_process` callback, though I'm not sure how to dynamically add that hook without modifying your code specifically for testing. I would see if you could reset the time before you create your model, that would probably be the simplest.